# Accessing a nested object with loop but too many undefines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-in-loop

I'm working with an object literal and trying to access the nested array and iterate through a loop but it keeps displaying 59 times and 5 times again as undefined in my console but then displays the arrays. How do I stop it from doing the undefined in the console? Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of console log]

```
var votingData = {
  candidates: [{
  name: "Harry S. Truman",
  party: "Democratic"
},
{
  name: "Thomas E. Dewey",
  party: "Republican"
},
{
  name: "Strom Thurmond",
  party: "Dixiecrat"
}]

}

for(var candidate in votingData) {
  if(votingData.hasOwnProperty(candidate)) {
    for (let i = 0, j = votingData[candidate].length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(votingData[candidate][i].name, votingData[candidate]
    [i].party);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the undefined logs when running your code in a console widow independently. Is there any other code likely to cause the undefined messages?

Comment: Using `for ... in` and checking whether there is a `length` property that can be coerced to a positive integer seems quite weird to me, but it shouldn't produce `undefined` outputs as your screen shows (cannot reproduce on chrome/FF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for/in` loop is contributing to the problem as it is not needed because `votingData` contains only one property, `candidates`.  Since there's just one property, you can access it directly, no need for a loop.

You only need to loop through the arrays which are in the `votingData.candidates` property and for that, you can either use a standard counting `for` loop, which you are doing or, even better, use the **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** mechanism for looping. It's better because it gives you direct access to the array element being looped over, without the need for an indexer and that allows the syntax to be much clearer, which in turn, tends to avoid bugs like this.

```js
var votingData = {
  candidates: [{
  name: "Harry S. Truman",
  party: "Democratic"
},
{
  name: "Thomas E. Dewey",
  party: "Republican"
},
{
  name: "Strom Thurmond",
  party: "Dixiecrat"
}],
};

// Just loop through the arrays in the votingData.candidates property
votingData.candidates.forEach(function(candidate) {
  // Now "candidate" is an object, so standard "dot notation" to access
  // any/all properties of the current object is the way to go.
  console.log(candidate.name, candidate.party);
});
```

Comment: "You are using a `for/in` loop on an array" - no, he is not. Only his formatting and naming are quite confusing.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yeah. I took another look and updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for throughly explaining the reasoning :) I'm a beginner and learning the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your first for loop and if statement are not necessary.
You're probably getting a lot of undefined because you have another property that's getting counted in the for-in statement.

Here's an example that doesn't use forEach if you prefer it.

**EDIT**

Formattied the data to improve readability

```js
var votingData = {
  candidates: [
    {
      name: "Harry S. Truman",
      party: "Democratic"
    },
    {
      name: "Thomas E. Dewey",
      party: "Republican"
    },
    {
      name: "Strom Thurmond",
      party: "Dixiecrat"
    }
  ],
  not_candidates : []
}

for (let i = 0, j = votingData.candidates.length; i < j; i++) {
  console.log(votingData.candidates[i].name, votingData.candidates[i].party);
}
```